# python separating leading newlines and remainder of string

Tags: python, python-3.x

#### summary

Given a string input, I am trying to capture leading newlines into a variable, while capturing the remainder of the string in a second variable.

#### input

```
msg0 = '' # control test
msg1 = 'a regular string'
msg2 = 'trailing newline\n'
msg3 = '\nleading newline'
msg4 = 'middle\nNewline'
msg5 = '\nMixed\nNewlines\n'
```

#### goal

I would like to create 2 variables:

1. contains any leading newlines (or else be empty)
2. contains the entire string *except* leading newlines.

Applied to the above strings, the desired output would be:

#### desired output

```
#msg0 control test
leading_newlines = ''
no_leading_newlines = ''

#msg1
leading_newlines = ''
no_leading_newlines = 'a regular string'

#msg2
leading_newlines = ''
no_leading_newlines = 'trailing newline\n'

#msg3
leading_newlines = '\n'
no_leading_newlines = 'leading newline'

#msg4
leading_newlines = ''
no_leading_newlines = 'middle\nNewline'

#msg5
leading_newlines = '\n'
no_leading_newlines = 'Mixed\nNewlines\n'
```

The control test `msg0` is just to show I don't have any exceptions with whatever solution I try.

#### attempt

I built the following regex:

```
import re
regex = re.compile(r'^(\n*)([^\n]*\n*)$')
leading_newlines = regex.sub('\\1', msg<n>)
no_leading_newlines = regex.sub('\\2', msg<n>)
```

I did of course try other patterns, but this one was the closest I could get. I'm aware the regex doesn't make sense for `msg4` or `msg5`, but my initial attempted pattern: `r'^(\n*)(.*)$'` fails for all messages except the control test.

#### problem

The above attempt works for `msg1`, `msg2`, and msg3`. However, it fails completely for` msg4`and`msg5`, both of which return the entire string from beginning to end for both variables.

#### full repl code for reproducing attempt

```
import re
regex = re.compile(r'^(\n*)([^\n]*\n*)$')

msg0 = ''
msg1 = 'a regular string'
msg2 = 'trailing newline\n'
msg3 = '\nleading newline'
msg4 = 'middle\nNewline'
msg5 = '\nMixed\nNewlines\n'

regex.sub('\\1', msg0)
regex.sub('\\2', msg0)



regex.sub('\\1', msg1)
regex.sub('\\2', msg1)



regex.sub('\\1', msg2)
regex.sub('\\2', msg2)



regex.sub('\\1', msg3)
regex.sub('\\2', msg3)



regex.sub('\\1', msg4)
regex.sub('\\2', msg4)



regex.sub('\\1', msg5)
regex.sub('\\2', msg5)
```

Output:

```
#msg0 -- correct
''
''

#msg1 -- correct
''
'a regular string'

#msg2 -- correct
''
'trailing newline\n'

#msg3 -- correct
'\n'
'leading newline'

#msg4 -- WRONG
'middle\nNewline'
'middle\nNewline'

#msg5 -- WRONG
'\nMixed\nNewlines\n'
'\nMixed\nNewlines\n'
```

Notice that `msg4` and `msg5` both return the entire string in each of their regex substitutions, while `msg1` through `msg3` properly yield the desired output shown above.

#### Question

Can anyone correct my attempt or suggest another solution? I'm not married to regex if there's another approach here. It simply needs to return string types that fulfill the desired output and can be loaded into variables.

**Note** The above input is simplified. There may be any number of leading newlines, and the remainder of the string could contain any characters.

*Python 3.6.8*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> my initial attempted pattern: `r'^(\n*)(.*)$'`

This was the correct approach, but you need to make `re` treat `\n` like any character to include it in the second capture group.

```
re.match(r'(\n*)(.*)', msg, flags=re.DOTALL).groups())
```

If you use `re.match`, `^` is unnecessary because it already matches from the beginning of the string. `$` is unnecessary because you capture everything to the end of the string.

Results for the given examples:

```
('', '')
('', 'a regular string')
('', 'trailing newline\n')
('\n', 'leading newline')
('', 'middle\nNewline')
('\n', 'Mixed\nNewlines\n')
```

See https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#regular-expression-syntax:

> `.`
>
> (Dot.) In the default mode, this matches any character except a newline. If the DOTALL flag has been specified, this matches any character including a newline.

Answer (score 1):

This (native python)?

```
msgs = [
 '', # control test
 'a regular string',
 'trailing newline\n',
 '\nleading newline',
 'middle\nNewline',
 '\nMixed\nNewlines\n',
 '\n\nSeveral leading',
 '\n\n' # only leading new lines
]

def find_index(s):
    for i,c in enumerate(s):
        if c != '\n':
            return i
    return len(s)

for (i, msg) in enumerate(msgs):
    print("\nmsg", i)
    j = find_index(msg)
    leading_newlines = msg[:j]
    no_leading_newlines = msg[j:]
    print("leading_newlines =", repr(leading_newlines))
    print("no_leading_newlines =", repr(no_leading_newlines))
```

Output:

```
msg 0
leading_newlines = ''
no_leading_newlines = ''

msg 1
leading_newlines = ''
no_leading_newlines = 'a regular string'

msg 2
leading_newlines = ''
no_leading_newlines = 'trailing newline\n'

msg 3
leading_newlines = '\n'
no_leading_newlines = 'leading newline'

msg 4
leading_newlines = ''
no_leading_newlines = 'middle\nNewline'

msg 5
leading_newlines = '\n'
no_leading_newlines = 'Mixed\nNewlines\n'

msg 6
leading_newlines = '\n\n'
no_leading_newlines = 'Several leading'

msg 7
leading_newlines = '\n\n'
no_leading_newlines = ''
```